# difference in expected argument type and provided argument in printf

Tags: c

I wanted to ask whether the following statement where `printf()` has been provided with  a type `int` where it expected a type `char` will invoke UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR. If not, what exactly is the step will be taken to make it compatible with expected type.  Will `a` be shortened to char type??

```
   int a = 65;   
   printf("%c", a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable arguments are subject to the default argument promotion, eg `char` will be promoted to `int`, `float` to `double` (that's the reason why you only have a single format specifier to print both single and double precision floating point values).

So passing an `int` instead of a `char` is perfectly valid and even desirable, as character literals are of type `int` anyway. According to the C99 spec, section 7.19.6.1 §8, on seeing the conversion specifier `%c`, `printf()` expects an argument of type `int` and will then go on and cast this value to `unsigned char`.

This means the following is guaranteed to output `a`, as conversion of signed to unsigned types is well-defined:

```
int a = 'a' + UCHAR_MAX + 1;
printf("%c", a);
```

Comment: Shorter types get promoted to longer, not opposite. And where it is defined that character literals are ints, not chars ?

Comment: @qrdl: ISO C99, section 6.4.4.4 §10: "An integer character constant has type int."; also, where did I say that a longer type gets promoted to a shorter?

Comment: @Christoph Sorry, I'm wrong about single character literals. Multi-character literals are implementation-defined (as specified by C99 section 6.4.4.4), but single-character literals indeed are ints.
I understood your statement "passing an int instead of a char is perfectly valid" as "int gets promoted to char", however in this context it didn't mean that, my bad.
I'd write it differently - "on seeing %c printf() expects int and casts it to unsigned int, a specified by section 7.19.6.1 §8 of C99"

Comment: @christopher
thanks for ur reply .
int a = 'a' + UCHAR_MAX + 1;
can u explain the significance of the above statement!,will'nt the value of a will be this after ur assignement on a machine where the size of char is 1byte:256+65

Comment: @qrdl: clarified; @mawia: `a = 'a' + UCHAR_MAX + 1 = 97 + 255 + 1 = 353`; when converting to `unsigned char`, you'll get back the original value as `(unsigned char)353 = 353 % 256 = 97 = 'a'`

Comment: @Cristoph: actually I don't think it's guaranteed to print 'a'. Suppose that int is the same size as char on your implementation. Then the addition overflows, and IIRC overflow of a signed integer is undefined behaviour. So it could print 'b'. Pretty unlikely implementation choice, of course, since sane processors tend to support arithmetic wraparound these days...

Comment: Of course if you're lucky it'll be a compiler warning ("constant expression overflows type", or something like that), but I don't think compilers are required to evaluate addition of constants before runtime.

Comment: @onebyone: nice catching that; yes, singned integer overflows are undefined, but it should work if you convert the character constant to `unsigned` and `UINT_MAX + 1` is a multiple of `UCHAR_MAX + 1`; adding this to the answer might only add confusion, so I think I'll leave it as-is